# How to convert a.jar to another custom extension?

Tags: java, file, jar, extension-methods, converters

I hope you are doing well, I usually had a little question I come here and I find it but for 1 week I've been stuck and I can't find answers or I'm looking for bad but so I come here and ask it.

How to convert a .jar to another custom extension like.jar ---> .willy? Is it possible to do that?

I don't just want to change the extension with a right click but really a conversion like that if the person changes the extension to.jar if he opens it with WinRAR it puts him corrupted file it's to launch the file.willy for example but without having it in.jar

Thank you in advance for your help